# How to add attribute in jquery to a moustache template

Tags: mustache

How to add attribute in jquery to an existing mustache template?

```
Here is the mustache template. I want to add the attribute bookindex dynamically
I would like to add it to the div level.

<script id="bookviewtemplate" type="text/template">
        <div class="bookclass" id="bookid" >
<img src='{{volumeInfo.imageLinks.smallThumbnail}}' style="float: left" />  Title: {{volumeInfo.title}}
    <div>  Author(s) : {{volumeInfo.authors}} </div>
    <div>  Publisher : {{volumeInfo.publisher}} </div>
    <div>  Published Date : {{volumeInfo.publishedDate}} </div>
        </div>
        </script>
```

here is where I try to add new attribute. I did try with attr and it did not work either. More details

```
$('#bookid').prop("bookindex", objkey);
template = $('#bookviewtemplate').html();
```

Comment: Later when the book is clicked I want retrieve the index value from bookindex  using "this". 
    
    click on title to see details. 
           
    
    so I can populate an array index in another view in the application
    
    I don't see the bookindex being populated. Also obj is not returning null of course. I have working on this for a very long time.`enter code here`
    
    Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: //click on title to see details
        $(".bookclass").on('click', function () 
    {     
     $(".bookclass").css("background-color","");
    //$(this).css("background-color","#DDEEFF");
    // assign bookid value to the hidden input text in class
     obj = $(this).attr("bookindex");